# WebRequest.GetResponse - The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Tags: vb.net, webrequest

I am trying to connect to a website but it keeps returning this error even though i can reach the website in my browser:

> An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
>   but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not
>   Found.

I'm pretty sure my code is correct as I've used the same code a lot recently but cannot work out why it returning an error, any suggestions?
My Code:

```
OddsTodayREQUEST = WebRequest.Create("http://www.betexplorer.com/next/soccer/")
Using OddsTodayRESPONSE As WebResponse = OddsTodayREQUEST.GetResponse()
            Using OddsTodayREADER As New StreamReader(OddsTodayRESPONSE.GetResponseStream())
                OddsTodayHTML = OddsTodayREADER.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: 404 = the page does not exists. Can you hit that exact page on the site in your browser?

Comment: Yes I can reach it in my browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add UserAgent as [@ChaseRocker mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46105400/1501497), In addition to his answer, It's better to use AutomaticDecompression property of HttpWebClient and you may add Accept header. I also used `OddsTodayRESPONSE.GetResponseStream()` in `Using` statement.

```
Dim OddsTodayREQUEST As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.betexplorer.com/next/soccer/")
OddsTodayREQUEST.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
OddsTodayREQUEST.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.Deflate 'Decompressing makes the request be done faster
OddsTodayREQUEST.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0"
Using OddsTodayRESPONSE As HttpWebResponse = OddsTodayREQUEST.GetResponse()
    Using OddsTodayRESPONSESTREAM = OddsTodayRESPONSE.GetResponseStream()
        Using OddsTodayREADER As New StreamReader(OddsTodayRESPONSESTREAM)
            OddsTodayHTML = OddsTodayREADER.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much for this explanation ,works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2):

The site wants a User Agent added to the request. You can google `What's my user agent?` to find your own and add it like this:

```
OddsTodayREQUEST.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)"
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much for helping me, is it best to include a User Agent for scraping all sites like this or just the ones that require a User Agent? If the latter, how do you know that the website requires one?

Comment: I would recommend you include the User Agent if you want to replicate what a web browser does. Also, I was only able to determine that the website required it thru testing. I got the same 404 error you did, so I added a User Agent and it worked.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for taking the time, ill include it on all future projects

Comment: wow, seriously dude you made my day, I was struggling to solve the issue, and it is this simple. your solution got my issue fixed. Thanks.